# How to remove text before delimiter?

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I need help on removing text after `);` and before `|` delimiters in all lines of a text file. I.e:

```
 SUBSCIBER_MSISDN=6289666195060');BEGIN DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(5); END-- rKSy|
```

And the result supposed to be like this

```
SUBSCIBER_MSISDN=6289666195060|
```

Any idea how to remove that part? It is a big file.

I will go crazy if I have to used `sed`.

Comment: Your example appears to correspond with "remove text **after** delimiter".

Comment: Beware asking for a generic action: do you wish to edit **every** line containing a quote in your big file, or is there additional context that needs to be present? I'm particularly suspicious of the apparent type in "SUBSCIBER", and also that this is apparently SQL where single quotes are ubiquitous, and you are removing syntax like `);`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming what you're showing is a complete line from some input file:

```sh
sed "s/'.*/|/" file >newfile
```

This would replace everything after the first `'` character on each line with a `|` character.  The result would be written to a new file by means of a redirection.  I'm using double quotes around the `sed` expression since a single quoted string can't ever contain a single quote character.

Given you example data, this would produce

```
 SUBSCIBER_MSISDN=6289666195060|
```

If you additionally want to remove blanks from the start of the line (your example seems to do this):

```
sed -e "s/'.*/|/" -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' file >newfile
```

or,

```
sed "s/'.*/|/; s/^[[:blank:]]*//" file >newfile
```

If you have an aversion to `sed`, you can employ `awk` to do the exact same transformation:

```
awk '{ sub("'"'"'.*", "|"); sub("^[[:blank:]]*", ""); print }' file >newfile
```

The funky looking `'"'"'` is a quoted single quote. It has to be double quoted outside of the single quoted string that constitutes the `awk` code.  We could also use `'\''`, i.e.

```
awk '{ sub("'\''.*", "|"); sub("^[[:blank:]]*", ""); print }' file >newfile
```

Or, you could use the octal ASCII code for the single quote character:

```
awk '{ sub("\047.*", "|"); sub("^[[:blank:]]*", ""); print }' file >newfile
```